# Error occurs when creating a UIImage from a base64 string in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

Have someone managed to create a UIImage in swift 4 using a base64 string?

I tried several different approaches, but no one works.

**1.**

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: mediaFile, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
    let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
}
```

This one gives me an error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" at the place where initializing the Data object

**2.**

```
if let url = URL(string: base64), let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
    return image
}
```

This one also gives me an error "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" at the place where initializing the Data object

**3.**

```
let dataDecoded = NSData(base64Encoded: base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded as Data)!
```

This one cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to type 'Data' in coercion

Comment: The first one works for me without any problems. Check the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you, @the4kman. That is because I defined a class called 'Data' in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where is the problem.

That is simply because I have a class called 'Data' in my project, which overwrites the 'Data' class in swift.

"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" means that arguments in the function call don't match the function definition.